# Newbie Rails Geocoder reverse search undefined error (Fresh project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, rubygems, rails-geocoder

I have created a fresh rails project. It's running on the lastest rails version as i have just installed rails on my pc and it is using Postgre for the DB. I have added the `gem 'geocoder'` in the gemfile and bundle install it. I have create a scaffold `rails g scaffold location address:string latitude:float longtiude:float`

I have added the following code into the location model file which I got from the official geocoder website http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude,
  :address => :location
after_validation :reverse_geocode
```

I then tried testing it, however it doesn't work. I have tried looking and reading the documentation but couldn't find any useful information. Could someone help pls.

I am getting the error of undefined method `location ....' when trying to save. This error is shown in the def create function

Parameters:

> {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "location"=>{"address"=>"",
> "latitude"=>"48.8582", "longitude"=>"2.2945"}, "commit"=>"Create
> Location"}

Comment: Peeking at the documentation, that last argument `:address => :location` I think it means "fetch the address from geocoder and store it in a `location` property on the model". Your model doesn't seem to have a `location` property, thus the error (?). To test the hypothesis try removing that line (keep just the `reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude`).

Comment: Thanks you, this has fixed the code